# How to setup Jenkins shared library with Subversion

Tags: jenkins, svn, jenkins-shared-libraries

Every example I've seen for Jenkins shared library setup on the web is based on Git/GitHub.
Can anyone help me with that using Subversion?
I've struggled a lot but could not figure out what should be specified as the `Default version`.
I've tried many different combinations of `Project Repository Base`, `Include branches`, `Library Name` and `Default version` but none worked.

Attached is the screenshot of my SVN repository setup. I know it's not as per the standards though, it should work somehow as it's just a demo project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While setting up the shared library in **Configure System** --> **Global Pipeline libraries** select `Retrival Methond : Morden SCM` and `Source Code Management : Subversion` like below picture :
[image]

and When you select Subversion it will ask you to choose subversion specific branching name like below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your effort Samit. I could figure out this configuration step too. My question is more related to what values should be put into those fields while using subversion.

Comment: give the SVN url in `Project Repository Base`. create a Credentials and give the id in `Credentials `. what ever branch you are trying to include add that `Include branches`, so that when you use `@Library('shared-lib@branchName')` branchName on Jeninsfile . specify whatever branch you are planning to exclude in `Exclude branches`.

Answer (score 2):

if your lib svn path is https://192.168.1.1:8443/svn/trunk/JenkinsLib, then Project Repository Base will be https://192.168.1.1:8443/svn/trunk/ and Default version is JenkinsLib.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to tag a specific branch in SVN, so I just used a period (i.e. '.') in the DEFAULT VERSION field and that takes that HEAD of the repo.

The project repo base is just the svn:// path to your repo.

I hope that helps.

Comment: This may help but too open a solution it would be - exposing complete SVN server. Well I could figure out that by "version" the configuration is asking for a default branch or tag to be used. Still, thanks for your answer. :)